# Ошибка при миграции laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Я новичек в laravel. Помогите пожалуйста.

Ошибка в консоли при попытки осуществить миграцию:

```
Migrating: 2022_03_15_224441_add_permission_menu_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `permission_menu` add constraint `permission_menu_menu_id_foreign` foreign key (`menu_id`) re
ferences `menus` (`id`) on delete cascade)

  at D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

  1   D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   D:\DEV\OpenServer\domains\crm.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:501
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Файл миграции:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddPermissionMenuTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('menu_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
//        Schema::table('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
//            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
//            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');
//        });
    }
}
// второй файл миграции
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMenusTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('menus');
    }
}
```

Файл модели:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Admin\Menu\Models;

use App\Modules\Admin\Role\Models\Permission;
use App\Modules\Admin\Users\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{Й
    use HasFactory;
    const MENU_TYPE_FRONT = 'front';
    const MENU_TYPE_ADMIN = 'admin';

    public function perms() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'permission_menu');
    }

    public function scopeFrontMenu($query, $user) {
        return $query->
            where('type', self::MENU_TYPE_FRONT)->
            whereHas('perms', function($q) use($user) {
                $arr = collect($user->getMergedPermissions())->
                map(function($item) {
                        return $item['id'];
                    }
                );
                $q->whereIn('id', $arr->toArray());
        });
    }

    public function scopeAdminMenu($query, $user) {
        return $query->where('type', self::MENU_TYPE_ADMIN);
    }

    public function scopeMenuByType($query, $type) {
        return  $query->where('type', $type)->orderBy('parent')->orderBy('sort_order');
    }
}
```

Comment: Таблица menus в базе создана, на момент выполнения миграции «AddPermissionMenuTable»? Если нет, то воспользуйтесь свойством path команды migrate и сперва создайте таблицу menus.

Comment: Спасибо ща вопрос @liudmila-savateeva . Таблица menus создана предварительно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ваших миграциях типы столбцов первичного ключа таблицы menu и внешнего ключа таблицы permission_menu разные.
Создайте первичный ключ такой командой

```
Biginteger('Id', true, true)
```

Документация [Blueprint](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html)

Answer (score 0):

решил так, для таблицы permission_menus поменял:

```
Schema::create('permission_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->bigInteger('menu_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

А для таблицы menus:

```
Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('sort_order')->default(100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

И все заработало. Спасибо!

Еще пробовал делать так для таблицы menus оставлял:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

А для таблицы permission_menu:

```
$table->integer('menu_id')->unsigned();
```

и тоже все работало. Дело оказывается в несовпадении двух полей двух соединяемых таблиц.